# Gulp-Watch on Windows 7 Issue - Node.js, NPM and Gulp installed successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

I am super new to using Node.js, NPM and all these modern tools for better productivity and workflow.

So here are the details:

```
 Node version - v8.10.0
 Gulp CLI version - 2.0.1
 Gulp Local version -  3.9.1
 NPM version - 5.6.0
 Windows 7
 Node.js installed in D:/ProgramFiles
```

I've tried using gulp and it does work wonderfully with this script

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default',function(){
console.log('Gulp task created');

});

gulp.task('html' , function() {
    console.log('Something useful here');

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('/app/index.html', function() {
        gulp.start('html');
        });
});
```

So typing gulp does respond with the default task message. Typing gulp html does respond too with a console message. However, when i type gulp watch, it does work with following output.

```
 Starting 'watch'...
 Finished 'watch' after 7.99 ms
```

But whenever i make changes and save the index file, the cmd doesn't update. I've tried using Git Bash and other terminals. I've even installed previous node versions and tried solving this issue using those but no luck so far.

I tried editing the dependencies to an older version but that doesn't work too.

If anyone of you can help, I'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated with callback method to end process for a graceful exit and not use CTRL-C.**

```
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch('./data/index.html', function(){
    gulp.start(['someOtherGulpTask']);
    }); 
});
gulp.task('someOtherGulpTask', function () {
    gulp.src('./test/sometest.js')
        .pipe(gulpmocha(),setTimeout(function() {
        cb();
    }, 5000))
});
function cb(){
process.exit(1);
}
```

**Original answer below**

The order of execution of gulp tasks are -

1. the default task gets executed and then the subsequent ones unless the task 
   to be executed is specifically mentioned in the cmdline call to gulp as you 
   have mentioned - "gulp watch".
2. you can specify the order in the beginning of the gulpfile like

   gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
3. or, you can start a task explicitly like so,

   gulp.task('default',function(done){ 
   console.log('Gulp task created');
   gulp.start('watch');
   done();
   });

**done** is the callback that allows your waiting task to complete which is missing in your gulp file. Below is the complete gulp file that you can use to execute the watch task as you require.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default',function(done){
console.log('Gulp task created');
gulp.start('watch');
done();
});

gulp.task('html' , function() {
    console.log('Something useful here');

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('./data/index.html', function() {        
            console.log('Some changes done');
        });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it was good to know more about it. I tried using your code. Here's my result:

Starting default...
Gulp task created
Starting 'watch'...
Finished 'watch' after 8.33 ms
Finished 'default' after 15 ms 

-------- That's it. I do not get "Some changes done" message. Nor upon changing my index file the cmd updates the watch with any message or so. I've corrected the file path to mine but still the problem remains.

Comment: im not familiar with gulp-watch library but i think you should return the result of the watch function. see usage. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

i prefer not using gulp-watch though since gulp already has a function for that. Use gulp.watch instead of gulp.task

Comment: Thanks for that @bumblebeen - I tried changing the code and did not know about gulp.watch - tried it too Used the following code too  gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch('/app/index.html', function() {        
            console.log('Some changes done');
        });
});  ---- The code works, starts a watch but whenever a change is made to the file it doesn't detect. Not sure why none of the method is working for me.

Comment: Also, I think there is no need to return within this gulp task, until and unless we are using any src, pipe and dest. So it's pretty straight forward but am not sure why it isn't working. Since I am new to these things so I hope someone can really help and we can solve this problem together.

Comment: dont use absolute path '/app/index.html', use relative path instead like './app/index.html' or wild cards like ''app/**/*.html"

Comment: I have sent you the screenshot precisely for the reasons that you have outlined. It is very common to make silly mistakes like not saving the file after you made the changes or not using the "dot" before "/" like @bumblebeen has mentioned.

Comment: @user2347763 You are absolutely right so I took the time to carefully check each spelling, colons, and the other programming mistakes. I've tried it using gulp-watch and without it using gulp.watch but both of these seems to only start the watch. I then have to terminate by pressing Ctrl + C, as upon changing the file the watch doesn't update at all. As a newbie, you know how hard it can get to get started. So basically I need to learn a number of things day in and day out to be able to prepare myself as a freelance developer. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @Adnan to use a graceful exit, you will need to define a callback and make a call to it. Within the callback method, call process.exit(1) like in the updated part of this answer.:

Comment: @rjv I believe you are talking about user2347763 answer and image provided. Did that, but it isn't working for me. I have been trying this for a few hours now with no luck at all. Cross-checked everything. Not sure at all what's stopping it to run the gulp-watch or even gulp.watch

Comment: @Adnan Got you! I am user2347763 and rjv :D

Comment: The following code worked! var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
 gulp.start(['watch']);
});


gulp.task('html' , function() {
    console.log('Something useful here');

});


gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch('./app/index.html',['html']); 
});

I removed gulp-watch altogether and made calls using gulp.watch. It just worked, whew! - I seem to understand your provided cb() function but I need to up my skills to be able to understand the core. As I have just started with this Node.js NPM thing. I'll connect with you.

Comment: @rjv Thanks so much buddy! Oh so you are here with multiple usernames! :P

Comment: @Adnan Not really, I just changed it today for the first time after about 4 or 5 years being on SO! Glad to have helped, if you found my answer useful, please mark it as an accepted answer, if you can.

Comment: @rjv I'll just do that. Connected with you on LinkedIn

Comment: Post your queries on SO. You will get more response. Since you are into marketing and ads, connecting with me on LinkedIn will not help you much as my connections are more technical/technology.

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./data/index.html', ['html']);
});
```

Avoid gulp.start, it is not documented or recommended.

Comment: Thanks Mark for responding. I tried that, exactly what @bumblebeen suggested above. The code works enough to start a watch but whenever a change is made to the file it doesn't detect it, no CMD updates. Not sure why none of the method is working for me.

Comment: The watch glob: './data/index.html' is relative to your gulpfile.js location.  So, is the gulpfile.js just above the data folder?

Comment: Yes, gulpfile.js is just above the app folder. I've also renamed it to app. As a newbie, I do not know much to be able to solve the problem further. Therefore I had to come and ask from you.